# Update whole JSONB object in Postgres 12

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-12

I am having a hard time to replace the JSONB object I have in a column named `config` with a fresh JSONB object.

According to Postgres (12) documentation, one should use `jsonb_set` in order to update existing JSON records: I am trying to replace the existing JSONB with the following instruction:

```sql
UPDATE table SET config=jsonb_set(config, '{config}', '{"newKey":"newValue"}') WHERE myUpdateCondition;
```

The problem is, the couple `{"newKey":"newValue"}` is successfully added to `config` but the previous JSONB still exists in `config` column: my goal is to *totally* update `config` with just `{"newKey":"newValue"}`, leaving nothing of the previous JSONB behind.

I was reading about `jsonb_delete` but I did not found it in the official documentation.

How could I update JSONB `config` column by leaving nothing of the previous JSONB object and replace it completely with a new JSONB object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my goal is to totally update config with just {"newKey":"newValue"}, leaving nothing of the previous JSONB behind.

Then just assign the new value:

```
UPDATE table 
  SET config= '{"newKey":"newValue"}'
WHERE ...;
```